# tikzmath: how to define numbered variables by a loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmath

I would like to define `\x{1}, \x{2}, ...`; so why does the following not work?

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {math}
\begin{document}

\tikzmath{
int \i;
for \xValue in {2, 3, 6}{%
   for \i in {1,...,3}{%%  
      \x{\i}=\xValue;  
};};%  %%
}

Test:  x(1)= \x{1}, ~~~  x(2)= \x{2}, ~~~  x(3)= \x{3}
gives alway the last defined number.


I tried the same with 'evaluate' (TikZ-manual, page 704), but this has no effect:  
%\tikzset{
%evaluate={
%int \i;
%real \x; 
%for \xValue in {2, 3, 6}{%
%   for \i in {1,...,3}{%%  
%      let \x{\i}=\xValue;  
%};};%  %%
%}}
%
%Test:  x(1)= \x{1}, ~~~  x(2)= \x{2}, ~~~  x(3)= \x{3}.
%gives alway the last defined number.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Pgfmath supports arrays, but they are really just comma celimited strings, and it will only read them, not create them..You can however create macros with names like `\csname x1\endcsname` but you can only access them using `\csname` (parser will not accept `\x1` as a macro name).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LaTeX doesn't have an innate array-storage concept, so when you say `\x{1}`, it does not conjure up the first element of the `\x` array...rather it calls on the `\x` macro and passes it the argument `1` (assuming `\x` was looking for an argument).

However, packages such as `listofitems` establish the array concept, referred to as a "list":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\begin{document}
\readlist*\x{2, 3, 6}
Test:  x(1)= \x[1], ~~~  x(2)= \x[2], ~~~  x(3)= \x[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

As to how to make `tikzmath` acquire the same result, perhaps this accomplishes it (though I am no expert on `tikzmath`):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {math}
\begin{document}
\tikzmath{
int \i;
\i=0;
for \xValue in {2, 3, 6}{%
      \i=\numexpr\i+1\relax;
      \x{\i}=\xValue;  
};%  %%
}

Test:  x(1)= \x{1}, ~~~  x(2)= \x{2}, ~~~  x(3)= \x{3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Mmmh, isn't there a way to fix 'tikzmath'?

Comment: @cis I could not say about `tikzmath`; however, you have your nested loop set up to execute a total of 9 times. The first 3 times, `\x{\i}` (for `\i` equal to 1,2,3) is set to 2.  The next three times, they are set to 3, and the final three times, they are all set to 6, which is the result you achieve in your MWE.

Comment: @cis Please see the **ADDENDUM** to my answer.

Comment: Ok, super! .............